# connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, testing, socket.io, mocha.js, fastify

I trying test my application with web sockets around 2 days, but not resulting. When i initiate my application and connecting to ws in before hook all is ok, but when i splitting this tasks i getting error **connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000**

Before hook:

```
app = await getApplication();

const appResult = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  app.listen(3000, (err, address) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      reject(err);
    }
    addr = initSocket();
    resolve(void 0);
  });
});

await Promise.all([
  removeTokens(),
  removeUsers(),
  removeCollaborations(),
  removeRequests(),
  removeChats(),
  removePhotos(),
  removeStripeCustomers(),
]);

result = await createChatBetweenUsers(app);
result2 = await createChatBetweenUsers(app, 3);
simpleUser = await getSimpleUser(
  app,
  Object.assign({}, user, {
    email: 'test5@test.com',
    phone: `+3809689953731`,
  }),
);
simpleUser2 = await getSimpleUser(
  app,
  Object.assign({}, user, {
    email: 'test6@test.com',
    phone: `+3809689953742`,
  }),
);
```

Test suite:

```
it.only('should connect to chat where user exists', async () => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('We are in here');

    try {
      const opts = {
        ...options,
        query: {
          token: result.user1.token,
          idChats: [result.chat._id, result.chat._id],
        },
      };
      const client = io('http://localhost:3000', {
        ...opts,
        reconnectionDelay: 1000,
        reconnection: true,
        reconnectionAttempts: 10,
        transports: ['websocket'],
        agent: false,
        upgrade: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      });
      client.on('connect_error', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        return reject(e);
      });

      client.on('connect', () => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line
        expect(client.id).not.null;
        client.disconnect();
        return resolve();
      });
      client.on('error', (error) => {
        client.disconnect();
        return reject(error);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return reject(e);
    }
  });
});
```

In netstat tool after before hook I getting status of my application such as **TIME_WAIT**
[image]

And I turn on DEBUG=socket* in envirement variables in my npm script, it give me some information, but not helpfully:

```
socket.io:server initializing namespace / +0ms
  socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} +0ms
  socket.io-parser encoded {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} as 0 +0ms
  socket.io:server creating engine.io instance with opts {"path":"/app","initialPacket":["0"]} +2ms
  socket.io:server attaching client serving req handler +2ms
  socket.io:namespace removing initial packet +0ms
  socket.io:namespace removing initial packet +0ms
  socket.io-redis waiting for 1 responses to "clients" request +0ms
  socket.io-redis received request {"requestid":"HpaMAB","type":0,"rooms":[]} +2ms
  socket.io-redis received response {"requestid":"HpaMAB","clients":[]} +2ms
  socket.io-redis waiting for 1 responses to "clients" request +53ms
  socket.io-redis waiting for 1 responses to "clients" request +0ms
  socket.io-redis received request {"requestid":"DwqSsZ","type":0,"rooms":[]} +1ms
  socket.io-redis received request {"requestid":"rqIBRC","type":0,"rooms":[]} +1ms
  socket.io-redis received response {"requestid":"DwqSsZ","clients":[]} +1ms
  socket.io-redis received response {"requestid":"rqIBRC","clients":[]} +1ms
  socket.io-redis waiting for 1 responses to "clients" request +6s
  socket.io-redis received request {"requestid":"H3znE6","type":0,"rooms":[]} +2ms
  socket.io-redis received response {"requestid":"H3znE6","clients":[]} +1ms
  socket.io-redis waiting for 1 responses to "clients" request +46ms
  socket.io-redis waiting for 1 responses to "clients" request +1ms
  socket.io-redis received request {"requestid":"8u0QAe","type":0,"rooms":[]} +1ms
  socket.io-redis received request {"requestid":"RNQ2jE","type":0,"rooms":[]} +1ms
  socket.io-redis received response {"requestid":"8u0QAe","clients":[]} +1ms
  socket.io-redis received response {"requestid":"RNQ2jE","clients":[]} +0ms
    Connect to chat
We are in here
  socket.io-client:url parse http://localhost:3000 +0ms
  socket.io-client ignoring socket cache for http://localhost:3000 +0ms
  socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +0ms
  socket.io-client:manager opening http://localhost:3000 +0ms
  socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 20000 +4ms
  socket.io-client:manager readyState opening +1ms
  socket.io-client:manager connect_error +2ms
  socket.io-client:manager cleanup +1ms
```

And error from socket_error event:

```
Error: websocket error
    at WS.Transport.onError (C:\Users\mxxnseat\Desktop\herheadquarters\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transport.js:67:13)
    at WebSocket.ws.onerror (C:\Users\mxxnseat\Desktop\herheadquarters\node_modules\engine.io-client\lib\transports\websocket.js:157:10)
    at WebSocket.onError (C:\Users\mxxnseat\Desktop\herheadquarters\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:128:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mxxnseat\Desktop\herheadquarters\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:554:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:470:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:193:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:158:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  type: 'TransportError',
  description: ErrorEvent {
    target: WebSocket {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      readyState: 2,
      protocol: '',
      _binaryType: 'arraybuffer',
      _closeFrameReceived: false,
      _closeFrameSent: false,
      _closeMessage: '',
      _closeTimer: null,
      _closeCode: 1006,
      _extensions: {},
      _isServer: false,
      _receiver: null,
      _sender: null,
      _socket: null,
      url: 'ws://localhost:3000/app/?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.tYKh7Qq8_7nzypqdTXe3l_ATB3NEqru-sukeB4FZc84&idChats=6234b485bedf8836a0b7a38b%2C6234b485bedf8836a0b7a38b&EIO=3&transport=websocket',
      _req: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    type: 'error',
    message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000',
    error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1132:16) {
      errno: -4078,
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 3000
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE: my application stopped after **before** hook

Comment: App.listen returns a promise, you don't need to adde a promise wrapper. Did you try to set the host '0.0.0.0'? You should find it in the documentation